# .txt file shows contents of directory and sub-directories and all of their files and directory permissions

Tags: linux

Im trying to learn linux but Im stuck on one task.

Create single file called outputa.txt which shows information:

contents of directory and sub-directories and all of their files and directory permissions

I upload my directory  structure 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `tree`:

```
tree -p > outputa.txt
```

Example:

```
$ tree -p > outputa.txt
$ cat outputa.txt
.
├── [drwxr-xr-x]  directorya
│   └── [drwxr-xr-x]  directoryb
│       └── [-rw-r--r--]  file1.txt
└── [-rw-r--r--]  outputa.txt

2 directories, 2 files
```